# Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website. SELENIUM

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access crunchbase.com using selenium/python and Chrome but I am getting **"Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website."**

My login code so far:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
```

and even if I press and hold the button, it will ask me to try again
[image]

is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try: https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth.
However, it should be noted that it is not ethical to use bots if the site owners do not want it.

For chrome explicitly: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver